# Migrating from Travis to GitLab CI with Docker

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm migrating from Travis to GitLab CI and I'm struggling to get Docker working:

`.gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```
image: docker:latest

services:
  - docker-dind

stages:
  - build
  - test

before_script:
  - apk add python3 python3-dev python3-pip
  - pip3 install --upgrade pip
  - pip3 install --no-cache-dir docker-compose
  - export REACT_APP_USERS_SERVICE_URL=http://127.0.0.1


compile:
  stage: build
  script:
    - docker-compose up --build -d


test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - docker-compose exec users python manage.py test

after_script:
  - docker-compose down
```

The build error throws:

```
ERROR: Job failed: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for docker-dind, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login' (executor_docker.go:188:0s)
```

How do I troubleshoot this ? I haven't needed docker login until now.

**Edit:**
After researching on GitLab docs and from similar SO topics I got to this:

```
image: docker:stable

services:
  - docker:dind

stages:
  - build
  - test

before_script:
  - apk add python python-dev python-pip
  - pip install --no-cache-dir docker-compose
  - export REACT_APP_USERS_SERVICE_URL=http://127.0.0.1

compile:
  stage: build
  script:
    - docker-compose up --build -d


test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - docker-compose exec users python manage.py test

after_script:
  - docker-compose down
```

Error output reads:

```
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.10/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
  pip (missing):
    required by: world[pip]
```

Comment: What is the first file we are looking at? Your pipeline for for gitlab?

Comment: Sorry that's gitlab-ci.yml file. I edited the post.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to establish new pipeline.

Comment: What is `docker-dind` supposed to be? You can refer to existing images in the services section, but I cannot find this image on docker hub...

Comment: `docker-dind` supposed to be a docker daemon that GitLab CI utilizes for its users.

Answer (score 1):

It's `docker:dind`, not `docker-dind`.

```
services:
  - docker:dind
```

Comment: Well spotted, Michael ! I got little bit further now.

Answer (score 1):

This is the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file that got it running:

```
image: docker:stable

services:
  - docker:dind

stages:
  - build
  - test

before_script:
  - apk add --no-cache py-pip python-dev libffi-dev openssl-dev gcc libc-dev make
  - pip install --no-cache-dir docker-compose
  - export REACT_APP_USERS_SERVICE_URL=http://127.0.0.1

compile:
  stage: build
  script:
    - docker-compose up --build -d


test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - docker-compose exec users python manage.py test

after_script:
  - docker-compose down
```